# Bar ware - What kind of glass is this?

Tags: cocktails, glass

I'm trying to purchase some of these cocktail/martini glasses, but I can not find a name for them.  If you search martini, you get a traditional martini glass (straight sides).  If you search for a cocktail glass, you get high balls and low balls.

Anyone know the name of this glass?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks a champagne coupe, like [this](http://www.elegantwoman.org/images/etiquette-proper-table-setting-champagne-coupe.jpg).

[image: screenshot]

Did you ever see pyramids of glasses where a butler fills the top one and let the champagne flow? I think that's the type of glass used, like [this](https://encrypted-tbn2.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnO0c8T97Qv73EqMKjISiq7DzgfSjClfdlHgWSxHJCvxVlLey8).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have seen those, and that was my first thought.  But - I wonder is there a difference between a champagne glass and an old school cocktail glass?  Maybe I'm just being too specific and that's exactly what the glass is...

Comment: The savoy champagne coupe/saucer is a nice refinement on this.

Comment: They're also referred to sometimes as Coupettes. They're more or less interchangeable with straight sided martini glasses, assuming the volume is comparable. Some people find it easier drinking from coupes. In my opinion, it's easier to drink faster from a coupe. For any drink you want to sip and savour slowly (Martinis, Manhattans, and other stirred, strong drinks), the straight edged glass is probably better.

Answer (score 4):

I think it may be just a matter of scale but your pic makes me think of a [margarita glass](http://www.partyyards.com/products/plastic-margarita-glasses). Of course there are many styles of margarita glasses that look similar (but not quite the same...)

[image]

Comment: Margarita was the first that came to my mind too, however the champagne coupe looks identical, it seems...

Comment: @huzzah: Pretty sure there's a huge size difference. Margaritas are usually much bigger than a normal quantity of champagne (think of a champagne flute). I found one picture of [a champagne coupe alongside a flute and a wine glass](http://www.hlswatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/wine-glasses-3.jpg) that would seem to back this up. The OP's picture looks much more like the size of a margarita glass to me.

Comment: @jefromi, actually, the OP's pictured glass, with the boston shaker in the background gives it a size that seems in line with a champagne coupe.  You are correct that a margarita glass is much bigger...if you look at the boston shaker in the OP's pic, the glass in question is shorter than the shaker...probably wouldn't be the case with a margarita glass.  You could be right but I am at this point assuming it's a champagne coupe.

Answer (score 2):

Its a Coupe, or to use it's original full name: a Champage Coupe. As you seem to be suggesting, you want glasses of this kind for drinking cocktails out of, rather than Champagne. And you're not alone.

[Coupe's were the traditional choice for drinking Champagne, reaching a peak of popularity in the early 20th century](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champagne_stemware). However they aren't really ideal for Champagne, as the large surface area encourages loss of bubbles, and fails to hold on to the aromas (whereas a Champagne Flute steers the lovely smells toward the nose more easily).

[More recently, quality cocktail bars have reverted to using these Coupe style glasses in place of Martini glasses](http://chanticleersociety.org/forums/p/380/2866.aspx). This is partly because they are more practical than straight sided Martini glasses, that are easy to spill from. More importantly its been a way for craft cocktail bars to separate themselves from mass produced, syrupy cocktails, churned out in massive Martini glasses in mainstream bars. The Coupe has a more old fashioned feel (the Speakeasy trend has been around for a few years now, with few signs of dying out) and Coupe glasses tend to be small. The craft cocktailarians point out that a cocktail "served up" will warm up quickly, as by definition it doesn't have ice in it. So it's better to serve these drinks in small traditional glasses (so you can drink the drink before it warm's up) rather than the massive Martini glasses that are so popular in retail outlets.

A quick search for Champagne Coupe, should find you a few sources to buy from.